# Can multiple VS 2010 code snippets be stored in the same file?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I have about 10 code snippets I want to use in a demo in Visual Studio 2010.  Does each code snippet need to be stored in a separate `snippetName.snippet` file?  Or, can I have all snippets in one file?

VS complains when I add a 2nd snippet to a file.  Maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171423%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) the `<CodeSnippets>` element may contain multiple `<CodeSnippet>` elements.  I'm not sure how you are adding your second code snippet to the file, but my guess would be to add another `<CodeSnippet>` section for each additional code snippet you wish to include.

Comment: Thanks. By default, adding a snippet does not create a parent `<CodeSnippets>` element.  That was the trick.